# globally switching a boolean using a function in python

Tags: python, function, scope, global

My objective is to create a function that take a global boolean as a parameter and flips its value.

I am using a function to initiate the global parameters.

I figured out a way to implement what i wanted to implement in my project, but a functionality like this would be a lot more efficient.

I figure its something regarding scope, but i am not sure how to implement it correctly in python... please help!

```
def boolswitch(boolean: bool):
   if boolean == True:
        boolean = False
   else:
       boolean = True


def initiate():
    global x, y
    x = True
    y = False


initiate()

print(x)
boolswitch(x)
print(x)

print(y)
boolswitch(y)
print(y)
```

it simply does nothing to the argument, *i tried most things...*

Comment: Is this in a class? What is the purpose of initiate?

Comment: the purpose of initiate is to replicate a similar situation in which i found myself in my project. This is not in a class.

Comment: `boolswitch` cannot work, as it takes a *value*, not the variable, as an argument. What would it do with `boolswitch(True)`, try to change the value of `True` to `False`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to pass a boolean by reference across threads and modules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43229939/how-to-pass-a-boolean-by-reference-across-threads-and-modules)

Comment: Python simply does not have the kind of pass-by-reference semantics of some other languages.

Comment: figured if i reassing `x = boolswitch(x)` (adding `return boolean` to the function) it works... i still wonder if there is a way to make this work without reassigning the variable...

Comment: If you need to do this, you probably need to reconsider your code structure. Perhaps you are thinking through this in a wrong direction. We might need further details to help you on that though.

Comment: @BožoStojković you are right... how would someone think about implementing this kind of functionality? what kind of details do you need?

Comment: I was writing my comment and didn't see you already posted another comment. Reassigning the variable is probably the way to go, depending on your requirements.

Answer (score 1):

figured if i reassing `x = boolswitch(x)` (adding `return boolean` to the function) it works... i still wonder if there is a way to make this work without reassigning the variable...